# Unable to Set HTACCESS to url_rewrite

Tags: linux, .htaccess, mamp, mamp-pro

I have .htaccess in the root of my project but its not re-directing as expected.

**My app is trying to call:**

http://localhost:8888/api/User `//via mamp`

**But my node backend is running and anything after API may change due to the endpoint:**

http://localhost:1377/projname-api/User `//via node`

**I have tried:**

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8888/api
RewriteRule (.*) http://localhost:8888/projname-api/$1 [R=301,L]
```

But i get a 500 server error in htaccess. I have re-written url's in .htaccess before but can not understand what i'm doing wrong.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: This didnt work. @anubhava because the rewrite url is different.

Comment: @anubhava look again. I have 2 localhost urls (different ports)

Comment: @anubhava i have listed above http://localhost:8888/api/User and http://localhost:1377/projname-api/User - are you on mobile reading this?

Comment: @anubhava api is hosted on port 1377 as stated above.

Comment: Why are you trying to "redirect" the request, isn't `localhost:1377/projname-api` intended to be hidden from the user? But this is also a different _port_ (as you've repeated in comments), yet your directive is redirecting to the _same_ port? "I have re-written url's in .htaccess before" - Although you are seemingly trying to implement a redirect, not a rewrite. (You can't "rewrite" to a different port.) However, with the limited information given, it would seem mod_rewrite may not be enabled - but you need to check your server's error log for details of the 500 error to confirm this.

Comment: this works on iis... i am trying to rewrite symlinks @MrWhite the front end is angular backend is node. when i run the app iuts looking for the api over 8888 mamp instead of 1377 node. Hope this makes since. It works on iis mod_rewrite url.

Comment: `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^localhost:8888/api` makes little sense, `localhost:8888/api` is not a _host name_. Only `localhost` is the host name here.

Comment: @CBroe Although the comparison here is against the `Host` header, which also includes the port number (if present on the request).